# Eigenvalues of Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here is my Question.

> Prove or disprove : There is a real $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$ such that $A^2 + 2A + 5I = 0$ iff $n$ is even.

What i have done is I started with polynomial representation of the equation. I know that their roots are imaginary. But what is the relation if $n$ is even or maybe odd to the matrix. Anyone can help?

Comment: @DonAntonio: $\exists A \in {\rm Mat}_n(\mathbb R) : A^2 + 2A + 5I = 0 \iff 2\mid n$.

Comment: So are you saying that the statement is true for any direction?

Comment: You are saying this, I have just rewritten your statement as a formula.

Comment: But the way, is the statement true?

Comment: The basic idea is the following: If $n$ is odd, $A$ is forced to have a real eigenvalue, which is impossible if $A^2 + 2A + 5 = 0$ (see (1) in my hint below). If $n$ is even, you can use the given matrix below as a replacement for $i$ and so construct matrices corresponding to the two complex roots of $X^2+X+5=0$

Comment: Ok I got it. I can do it now.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: (1) For odd $n$, any real matrix $n \times n$ has a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ with eigenvector $x$, say. For any polynomial $p$ we have $p(A)x = p(\lambda)x$. Now: Can $p(A) = 0$ hold in this case?

(2) If $n=2k$ is even, recall that $\def\Id{\mathop{\rm Id}}\begin{pmatrix}0 &-\Id_k \\ \Id_k & 0 \end{pmatrix}^2 = -\Id_n$.